# SSLHandshakeException for Google Recaptcha

Tags: java, ssl, recaptcha, handshake

I am using a Java 1.7 application running on a JBoss7.0.2.Final server.

I created a REST endpoint to handle user login. This works fine, but when I call Google's recaptcha (v2) url (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify), I get the following error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:
> handshake_failure

This was working with no errors yesterday, and there have been no changes on our server, so I suspect something might have changed on googles end.

**Question**

Does anyone know why I have started to get this error today, and how I can resolve it?

**More info:**

I have tried building our application (mvn clean install) with the following paramaters, but it makes no difference.

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
```

**More Info:**

If I call Google's verify endpoint directly with Postman, I don't get the handshake error:

```
POST https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=seceret-key&response=rechapta
```

Also if I call it from another JBoss servers we have (localhost & another environment), it does not get the handshake error.

So something must not be correct on our server.

Answer (score 1):

Google has multiple Root CAs. You need to check the Google PKI repository for the current CAs and add all of them to the keystore to ensure SSL Handshakes work successfully at all times.
You can access the PKI repository here https://pki.goog/repository/

Answer (score 0):

I added Google's certificate (`*.google.com.cer`) to the servers cacerts (at the servers jre, e.g. `/home/jboss/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.161-2.6.12.0.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts`).  Restart the jboss server.

```
Owner: CN=*.google.com, O=Google LLC, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
Issuer: CN=GTS CA 1O1, O=Google Trust Services, C=US
Serial number: 6e4318b8d790165c0300000000badb8a
Valid from: Tue Nov 10 16:34:43 SAST 2020 until: Tue Feb 02 16:34:42 SAST 2021
```

The certificate can be copied from this url: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify.

[image]

(see https://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed/)

Comment: `scp *.google.com.cer jboss@dev.nexct.co:/home/jboss/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.161-2.6.12.0.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/security/`

Comment: sudo keytool -importcert -file ./*.google.com.cer -alias demo -keystore ./cacerts